# MFC EndDialog crashes when modal dialog does not have focus

Tags: c++, mfc

I am closing a modal dialog after I end a task, inside a separate thread from where I created a modal dialog:

```
void CmodguiApp::_notify_task_end() {
  processingDialog->EndDialog(0);
}
```

This works fine if my application has focus (therefore the modal dialog has focus). But this causes the application to crash if I change window while the modal dialog is on (for instance, if I leave the application processing and switch to Firefox or so).

What could be wrong?

Comment: Do not use EndDialog. Instead post a WM_CLOSE or WM_QUIT to your dialog window by PostMessage or SendMessage.

Comment: @hypheni solved it :)

Comment: @hypheni want to post answer to close the question?

Comment: added. Please close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not end the dialog with EndDialog. Instead PostMessage with WM_CLOSE or WM_QUIT to the dialog window.